# how to dispose object that is holding my file

Tags: php

I want to know how to dispose the objects in php. i am hold file with object glob( "*.msg") as $filename and want to use same file within same loop.
 error is : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft Office Outlook
**Description:** Cannot open file: 15-23-23.msg. The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program. Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click Properties to check your permissions for the folder.

Comment: Objects disposing is done by php automatically (Garbage Collector) and you can't do it manually. Try closing the file.

Comment: You certainly do _not_ want to open that file twice at the same time. That is not a good idea, at least not for writing.